# How to use wait() and notify() in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog, ui-thread

I am trying to open a AlertDialog. When this AlertDialog is opened, the threads need to wait for user input in order to continue its program. I read that I need to lock the object thats need to wait and notified. When I run this code on my phone. The alertdialog won't show, and it looks like the app is looping, because after a few seconds I get a message that the app isn't responding. Below you will find the code I wrote.. By the way. I am a virgin to android programming. So please be gentle :P

```
public class EditTagActivity extends Activity{  

AlertDialog alertDialog;

Runnable h = new Runnable()
{
    @ Override
    public void run() 
    {
        alertDialog.show();
        synchronized(g)
        {
            try 
            {
                Log.d("Threads", "g.wait()");
                g.wait();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
};

Runnable g = new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.d("Threads", "createAlertDialog()");
        createAlertDialog();
        runOnUiThread(h);
    }
};
public AlertDialog alert;
Runnable test = new dialogManager();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_tag);
    Log.d("Threads", "setup()");
    setup();
}

void setup() 
{
    Log.d("Threads", "g.run()");
    g.run();
}

void createAlertDialog() 
{
    Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Alert");
    alert.setMessage("Flaq");
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            synchronized(g)
            {
                Log.d("Threads", "g.notifyAll");    
                g.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            synchronized(g)
            {
                Log.d("Threads", "g.notifyAll");
                g.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog = alert.create();
}
```

}

Comment: You're doing the waiting on the UI thread itself, that won't work - the entire UI is just stuck. What exactly are you trying to achieve with all the waiting..?

Comment: hmm.. okay.. i changed my runnables into threads.. When a alertdialog is showed.. The thread that opened the alert dialog needs to wait for the user input..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Java's `Thread` and `Runnable` approach, you should use Android's `AsyncTask`, It helps you resolve this more simply by overriding the onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods to handle things just before and after running the code in background.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/2185634) has a good example for using the AsyncTask class.

Comment: You should [read more](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) about Threading in Android, it's important that you understand the usage of UI Thread and the background Threads.

Comment: Okay.. I will try that.. I will let you know when I got it working.. thanks in advance though